# Open activity from other activity

Tags: java, xml, button, android-activity, android-studio

I have a main activity (mottoscreen) after which an activity called circles opens up then from that activity I want to open up either one of the other two activities(sc_activity and or_activity). I have written the code for it but on clicking the buttons present in circles activity the next activity isn't showing up.

Circles Java file-

```
package com.apsdevelopers.mr.meteout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
public class circles extends mottoscreen {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.circles);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v)
{

    if (v.getId() == R.id.GOsc)
    {
        Intent I = new Intent(circles.this, sc_activity.class);
        startActivity(I);
    }

   else if (v.getId() == R.id.GOor)
    {
        Intent j = new Intent(circles.this, or_activity.class);
        startActivity(j);
    }


}

}
```

Sc_activity Java file-

```
package com.apsdevelopers.mr.meteout;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class sc_activity extends mottoscreen
{
    EditText name, ph, address, mass, thing;
    Button msg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sc_activity);

    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pin);
    String pinc = p.getText().toString();
    final int apsnumber= Integer.parseInt("8763597264");

    if (pinc.equals("753001") || pinc.equals("753002") || pinc.equals("753003") || pinc.equals("753004") || pinc.equals("753005") || pinc.equals("753006") || pinc.equals("753007") || pinc.equals("753008") || pinc.equals("753009")) {
        ph = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ph);
        address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        mass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mass);
        thing = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thing);
        msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.msg);
        msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String number = ph.getText().toString();
                String message1 = name.getText().toString();
                String message2 = address.getText().toString();
                String message3 = mass.getText().toString();
                String message4 = thing.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sc_activity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(apsnumber), null, number+message1 + message2 + message3 + message4, pIntent, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form sent successfully ! , now click on DONE",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: WE DONOT COVER THE PINCODE ENTERED BY YOU, PLZ ENTER A VALID PINCODE OF (CTC, ODISHA)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;

}
public void onButtonClick(View v)
{

    if (v.getId() == R.id.msg)
    {
        Intent I = new Intent(sc_activity.this, th_activity.class);
        startActivity(I);
    }


}
}
```

Sc_activity XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9acef6fe"
android:id="@+id/sc_activity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="NAME"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/ph"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="PHONE NUMBER"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="E.g.-5kg, 100 bottles... "
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mass"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="E.g.- metal scrap+newspapers, bottles+tyres...+"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thing"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:text="ADDRESS"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pin"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thing"
    android:text="THING"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/mass"
    android:text="AMOUNT"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pin"
    android:layout_marginTop="36sp"
    android:text="PINCODE"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ph"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SEND MESSAGE"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:background="#e33a9179"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thing"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView11" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Or_activity Java file-

```
package com.apsdevelopers.mr.meteout;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class or_activity extends mottoscreen
{
     EditText nam, pho, addres, mas, thinge;
  Button msg2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.or_activity);

        nam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nam);
    EditText p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin1);
    String pinc = p.getText().toString();
        final int apsnumber= Integer.parseInt("8763597264");
    if (pinc.equals("753001") || pinc.equals("753002") || pinc.equals("753003") || pinc.equals("753004") || pinc.equals("753005") || pinc.equals("753006") || pinc.equals("753007") || pinc.equals("753008") || pinc.equals("753009")) {
        pho = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ph);
        addres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        mas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mass);
        thinge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing);
        msg2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.msg2);
        msg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String number = pho.getText().toString();
                String message1 = nam.getText().toString();
                String message2 = addres.getText().toString();
                String message3 = mas.getText().toString();
                String message4 = thinge.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), or_activity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(apsnumber), null, number+message1 + message2 + message3 + message4, pIntent, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form sent successfully ! , now click on DONE",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: WE DONOT COVER THE PINCODE ENTERED BY YOU, PLZ ENTER A VALID PINCODE OF (CTC, ODISHA)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.msg2)
    {
        Intent I = new Intent(or_activity.this, th_activity.class);
        startActivity(I);
    }
}
}
```

Or_activity XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9acef6fe"
android:id="@+id/or_activity">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="NAME"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/nam"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pho"
    android:text="PHONE NUMBER"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nam"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pin1"
    android:text="PINCODE"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pho"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/addres"
    android:text="ADDRESS"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/mas"
    android:text="AMOUNT"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="E.g.- toys , clothes ...                                       "
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thinge"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thinge"
    android:text="THING"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textColor="#d4375a5c"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addres"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SEND MESSAGE"
    android:id="@+id/msg2"
    android:background="#e33a9179"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thinge"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thinge" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="E.g.-5 books,2 cricket bats..."
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mas"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please guide me where I did a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the following in your code:

1. Your circles.xml has two Buttons with id GOsc and GOor?
2. In your circles.xml you have set `android:onClick="onButtonClick"`for both buttons?
3. If both of the above result to yes, can you please paste your circles.xml file here as well?

Comment: i had forgotten to put the "onButtonClick" . its working now .thanks @Swagata A